# What table per type inheritance behaviors

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm

Given two entities: Parent, Child.

Table per type inheritance what does it do when:

1. You add an entity called Child, with all of its values left blank, but its Parent properties filled out. Will it add the child entity or just the Parent?
2. If the entity Parent with ID == id, exists, but it has no Child, will a query against the repository Child, with predicate ID == id, return anything? Ie. will such query be translated into left join or cross join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It will always try to add an entry into both tables
2. EF wouldn't return anything. The resulting SQL is a left join

Comment: If it is a left join, then it should return the child, since the parent in the parent table exists, and the child does not. Right?

Comment: It can't return a child if it doesn't exist. It produces something similar to SELECT ... FROM Children LEFT JOIN Parents ON ChildId = ParentId WHERE ChildId = @Id. Which retirns an empty result if ChildId doesn't exist

Comment: That's tricky but very informative. In my case the Child PK is actually also the FK to the Parent entity. I wonder if this will still hold.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you think EF will check the child entity, if all properties are nullable and if yes, then it will not save it? Why would it do that?? Also, the hiearchy mapping is rule, that if the entity is of child type, then it must have record in child table. So answer is probably no. Even when no property is set in child, it will still create record in the table.
2. How can EF tell if entity is of Parent type, when it didn't yet have chance to query it's type? So no, join will be generated every time.

Comment: To tell the truth, I dont know. But I believe left join is enough. It shouldnt be hard to make a testing example yourself and see what SQL is generated.